# Use a preventdefault to get out of the loop after pressing Enter key

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

**This is a complete revision of my initial question, all unnecessary resources and references were deleted**

I am tying the same event listener to 2 different elements: a button and Enter key, and it looks like the following:

```
var funcelement = function(){
    //function code
};


$('#buttonID').click(funcelement);


$('#inputID').keyup(function () {
   if (event.which == 13) {
      $('#buttonID').trigger('click');
   }
})
```

What I am trying to do is to prevent propagation of the enter key press if focus is on the submit button(#buttonID) by using preventDefault().

So I tried various combinations to make it work. The following is the latest result on my attempts

```
$('#inputID').keyup(function () {
   var hasfocus = $('#buttonID').is(':focus') || false;

   if (event.which == 13) {
      if (!hasfocus) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $('#buttonID').trigger('click');
         //hasfocus = true;
      }

      else {
         //event.preventDefault();
         //$('#buttonID').trigger('click');
     }

   }
})
```

After I enter a text into an input box and press Enter key, a confirmation window with yes/cancel buttons pops up with focus on yes button. Once I press Enter again, another window confirming that changes were made pops up with Ok button focused on it. Once I press Enter again, everything I need is being made.

However, there is one problem: after the last step is done, I am going back to the *if (!hasfocus)*  line.

How do I prevent that from happening? Once the stuff I need is done - I don't want to go into that line again.

Comment: I find that `stopPropagation` is almost always a bad choice. It kills event delegation and hides many issues that could lead to race conditions.

Comment: @zzzzBov Then, should I look into alternatives, like stopBubble?

Comment: .focus() is a function that sets the focus to that element. In order to simply check if the focus is on an element instead, jquery has the ":focus" selector. Use it like this: $('#buttonID').is(':focus')

Comment: @Cameron637 Ok, I will use it the way you showed me (thank you for that), but that doesn't answer the main question in OP.

Comment: I know, that's why I switched it to a comment.  I'm working on an answer for you.

Comment: @Cameron637 Thank you for your effort, I really appreciate it!

Comment: It sounds like what you actually are looking for is an `onSubmit` handler. You shouldn't need to trigger a button click from an enter key press - that's the default behaviour already.

Comment: @Bergi Currently looking into it as possible alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a parameter to into the function and stop the propagation there like so:

```
var funcelement = function(event, wasTriggeredByEnterKey){
   if (wasTriggeredByEnterKey && $('#buttonID').is(':focus')) {
       event.stopPropagation;
   }

    //function code
};


$('#buttonID').click(funcelement);



$('#inputID').keyup(function () {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        $('#buttonID').trigger('click', [true]);
    }
  }
)
```

**UPDATE**

In order to answer your revised issue, you should use the "keydown" event rather than "keyup" when working with alerts. This is because alerts close with the "keydown" event but then you are still triggering the "keyup" event when you release the enter key. Simply change the one word like this:

```
$('#inputID').keydown(function () {
   var hasfocus = $('#buttonID').is(':focus') || false;

   if (event.which == 13) {
      if (!hasfocus) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $('#buttonID').trigger('click');
         //hasfocus = true;
      }

      else {
         //event.preventDefault();
         //$('#buttonID').trigger('click');
     }

   }
})
```

Comment: Had to go out for a bit, sorry for late response. I went with exactly how you showed, however, it blocks Enter key.

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I tried it, it never enters into event.stopPropagation;

Comment: That means one of the conditions being met.  Check the value of wasTriggeredByEnterKey when it gets to the if statement, it should be set to true.  If it's not that, it must be the focus.

Comment: I will use your suggestion and try to rearrange logic a bit. I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: I have rearranged my question. See if that helps you find the answer better.

Comment: Who would've thought that a simple keyword will fix it! Upvote and accept, thanks a lot man!